# Limit involving the regularized incomplete beta function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, probability-distributions

Let $F(x;a,b)$ be the cumulative density function (cdf) of a Fisher distribution, then:
\begin{equation*}
F(x;a,b) = I_{\frac{ax}{ax+b}}\left(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{b}{2}\right), 
\end{equation*}
where $I_{x}(c,d)$ is the regularized incomplete beta function defined as: 
\begin{equation*}
I_{x}(c, d) = \frac{B(x; c,d)}{B(c,d)} 
\end{equation*}
where:
\begin{equation*}
B(x; c,d) = \int_{0}^{x} t^{c-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
B(c,d) = \int_{0}^{1} t^{c-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt.
\end{equation*}

The limit $\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}F(x;a,b)$ should be related to the cdf of a $\chi$-squared random variable. How can I prove this?

Comment: I believe you are looking for the following: If $X$ has an F distribution with $(a,b)$ degrees of freedom, then $aX$ has a $\chi^2_a$ distribution as $b\to \infty$? This is not quite what you have written.

Comment: Yes, I’m aware of this result. However, even if my question was written using a “probabilistic terminology”, my aim here is to try find that limit with a direct “analytical” proof (without using pdfs ecc ecc).

Comment: You don't need pdfs, basic convergence results is enough to show this. If this is indeed your actual question then the limit in your post should be $\lim_{b\to \infty }F(x/a;a,b)$. That was the point of my comment.